# Store and read high score results

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making a Windows Phone 8.1 app in Visual Studio 2013. I have two pages that retrieve points data asynchronously and a `Save Results` button at the page bottom. After a user presses the button, the result needs to be saved somewhere so that it can be later displayed on another `Scoreboards` page, where he can see how many points he have got previously.

Any idea how can I create something like that?
I have an idea with `SQLite` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the `ScoreboardPage` class, and when the user wants to view their scores, just navigate to this page from another page:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof (ScoreboardPage));
```

For the `SQLite` part, you have a great beginner tutorial on [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826602/Using-SQLite-as-local-database-with-Universal-Apps) but be sure to use **SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1**.

When you finish configuring SQLite you can use it to store your results, when the `Save Results` button is clicked. And then when you navigate to the `ScoreboardPage`, load the scores from the database in the `OnNavigatedTo` method of the page.